# Forbidden island taking items

Tags: forbidden-island

With an action, one may give items to another player. Can you take an item from a player with an action, or must you wait for their turn and have them give it to you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [rulebook](http://gamewright.com/gamewright/pdfs/Rules/ForbiddenIslandTM-RULES.pdf) only ever mentions being able to give a Treasure card as your action, so no you cannot use an action to take them from another player, you must wait until their turn to receive the card.

Also note that under the *Give a Treasure Card* action description on page 5, you cannot give special action cards (Helicopter Lift and Sandbags) to another player, you can only give the cards that match the four treasures in the game.